# Filtering a signal in time and frequency domain

Tags: python, time-series, fft

I am trying to filter in frequency domain. I have the parameters a,b (M-order numerator b and N-order denominator a ). In time domain i can to the following:

```
y_time_domain = lfilter(b, a, sig_noise)
```

where sig_noise in the noisy data.

How can I filter the sig_noise after FFT?

Comment: Suppress any frequency components (i.e. 0 them) you don't want and then take the inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: @ndc85430 i want to use a specific filter (used in time domain) but I don't know the cut off values